# how to show camera Icon on Image

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

```
 <View
        style={{
          borderRadius: 130 / 2,
          borderColor: '#000',
          backgroundColor: '#f89',
          height: 130,
          width: 130,
        }}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/G34Qbpv.jpg'}}
          style={{
            height: 130,
            width: 130,
            borderRadius: 130 / 2,
            zIndex: 0,
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            top: 90,
            backgroundColor: '#0f0',
            zIndex: 1,
          }}>
          <Icon
              name="camera" 
              size={30} />
        </View>
      </View>
```

I want to show Camera Icon on this Image:

[image: like snapshot image]

I want to show camera Icon on pics for Uploading a new image like this Image:[image], how can I do this show camera for uploading another pic.

Comment: can you give an example or reference what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to add camera icon on bird pics like above

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
You forgot specifying the position

```
 <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            top: 90,
            right : 0,
            position : 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: '#0f0',
            zIndex: 1,
          }}>
          <Icon
              name="camera"
              enter code heresize={30} />
        </View>
```